# big spaces between lines, HTML

Tags: html, css

I have this code in my webpage [webcovid19.live](https://webcovid19.live/)

```
<style>
h1 {

  padding: 20px;
}

h2 {

  padding: 20px;
}

p {

  padding: 20px;

}
h4 {

  padding: 20px;
}

</style>
....
<body>
<p> Data Source : Center for Systems Science and Engineering (CSSE) at Johns Hopkins University (JHU)</p>
<p> Powered by Google Data Studio &amp; Google BigQuery</p>
```

and I just realized that big spaces between lines is due to my style tag,
when I remove it, spaces are ok, Any idea ? I want this style for padding...

Here is screenshot:

[image: spaces screenshot]

Comment: you are adding padding

Comment: ok, so if I want text position from left, I need different tag right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all the `padding` to `padding-left`. It will still indent it from the left but will not affect up, down, right:

```
h1, h2, p, h4 {

  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thx, its working now !

Answer (score 1):

The `padding` property is actually a short-hand for four other properties:

`padding-right` `padding-left` `padding-top` `padding-bottom`

Any value applied to `padding` will be applied to all four of these, so padding is being added all around your elements. You neeed to use `padding-left` only.

Full, working code snippet:

```css
h1, h2, p, h4 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p> Data Source : Center for Systems Science and Engineering (CSSE) at Johns Hopkins University (JHU)</p>
<p> Powered by Google Data Studio &amp; Google BigQuery</p>
```

An additional point: to avoid having to add padding to every element individually, you could instead add a `margin-left` to its container (eg. `body`):

```css
body {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p> Data Source : Center for Systems Science and Engineering (CSSE) at Johns Hopkins University (JHU)</p>
  <p> Powered by Google Data Studio &amp; Google BigQuery</p>
</body>
```

Comment: yep, now I understood

Comment: @andrew I've added one other point to my answer – using `margin-left` on a single element instead of applying padding to several. Maybe something you also want to consider?

Comment: thx  for hint, for now its ok :)